# Cardinal arithmetic: $\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ = max( $\aleph_2$ , $2^{\aleph_0}$).

Tags: set-theory

For those interested this is Exercise 4.5 from Ernest Schimmerling's "A couse in set theory".

What i want to prove is $\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ = max( $\aleph_2$ , $2^{\aleph_0}$).

The inequality max(...) $\le$ $\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ is pretty straightforward.

Now for the other inequality.

If $\aleph_2$ $\le$ $2^{\aleph_0}$ the result follows easily.

My problem is if $2^{\aleph_0}$  < $\aleph_2$. It follows that $2^{\aleph_0}$ = $\aleph_1$, ie, we're assuming the continuum hypothesis. Is it possible to prove, assuming this, that $2^{\aleph_1}$ = $\aleph_2$ ? The remaining inequality would follow easily.

Help and thanks!

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make the notation nicer. For instance, typing `$\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$` gives $\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I'm gonna try tkz

Comment: Done, tkz for the tip.

Comment: How is maximum defined in transfinite cardinals?

Comment: @Raffaele The class of cardinals is well-ordered (assuming choice).

Comment: Who is this tkz fella?

Answer (score 5):

No, ZFC+CH does not prove that $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$. In fact, [beyond the obvious there are no restrictions on how the continuum function on regular cardinals can behave in ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), e.g. $$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1,\quad 2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_{17}, \quad 2^{\aleph_2}=\aleph_{17},\quad 2^{\aleph_3}=\aleph_{\omega^2\cdot 14 + 159}$$ is totally possible.

*EDIT: singular cardinals are **weird**, and there **are** extremely interesting rules for how the continuum function behaves on singular cardinals. E.g. it turns out that if $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal (that is, $2^{\aleph_n}<\aleph_\omega$ for all $n<\omega$), then we have $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$. This is a result of [pcf theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCF_theory), due to Shelah, and it is still fairly mysterious - Shelah is on record as asking ["Why the hell is it four?"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0102056.pdf).*

Instead, note that any map from $\omega$ to $\omega_2$ *(= any element of $\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}$ - it's a bit easier to think in terms of ordinals, here)* has range bounded by some element of $\omega_2$ (why? think about cofinality). Anything $<\omega_2$ has cardinality $\omega_1$, and there are $\omega_2$-many things $<\omega_2$; so we have $$\aleph_2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2\cdot(\aleph_1^{\aleph_0})$$ (fill in the steps here). But assuming CH, $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ (why?).

Comment: Somewhat pedantic note: there are no nontrivial restriction on how the continuum function behaves on _regular cardinals_.

Comment: @Wojowu Ah yes, that's quite important! Fixed.

Comment: I'm working on your answer, tkz